# European roads toll cost

Tags: openstreetmap, data, road, europe

I'm looking for a dataset or an API that provides information about toll costs of european roads.

Something similar to ViaMichelin, that is what we are using now, but preferably free of charge.

Does somebody know some free dataset with this information?

I was thinking in OSM, but I do not know if offers this information.

Comment: This is a question which I think would be more on-topic to research/ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: OSM is the right place to query for toll roads but the wrong place for querying toll *costs*.